# How can I move a mongoDB database from mLab to Digital Ocean for Parse Usage?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, digital-ocean, mlab

I'm a parse(Parse.com) user since I started app developing. But recently parse closed and I have to transfer all of my data.

---

I have successfully transferred all of my app data to Heroku (Parse Server) and mLab (mongoDB storage). However, when the volume of data is getting bigger and I'm not able to afford a high amount of charge on mLab's service.

Recently, I'm planning to build a mongoDB server on the Digital Ocean platform and transfer all of my data from mLab to it. However, it's really hard for me. I have searched though all of the website and none of them provide tutorials on it. I'm now stuck on the step of data migration.

I have successfully created a mongoDB server on it and created the SSH connection. I've tried a lots of methods, e.g. using Studio 3T (authorisation problem), create server backup via the mLab website (but I don't know how to restore to Digital Ocean). I have also tried adding the node.js for obtaining direct connection but it did not help.

---

All I want to do:

**Heroku (Parse Server) and mongoDB on mLab (Data Storage)**

--> **Heroku (Parse Server) and mongoDB on Digital Ocean (Data Storage)**

and a new standard MongoDB URI (mongodb://:@dsxxxxxx.xxxx.com:12345/) should appear

Comment: Have you tried using mongodump and mongorestore? Take a mongodump from the mLab database and mongorestore it to your Digital Ocean database. http://docs.mlab.com/backups/#dump-and-restore

Comment: I've tried that. I backed up the old database onto my computer. But I'm not able to use mongorestore to restore the backup to the new database. I've read though the documents and follow their instructions but not working.

Comment: What’s the error mongorestore is showing?

Comment: No error shown. I don't know how to perform mongorestore pushing local database to the online one. The website only provide the steps for restoring mongodb backup saved within the same server.

Comment: You don't have to be on the same server, you just need to specify the host name of the database you want to restore into. You run `mongorestore -h <hostname>:<port> -d <dbname> -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword> dumpdir/*` where `<hostname>` etc are the details of your digital ocean database. It will update the contents of `dumpdir` into your digital ocean db. See the documentation for details on how mongorestore works: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/